# split function does not return any observations with large dataset

Tags: r, list, dataframe, split, bigdata

I have a dataframe like this:

```
seqnames       pos     strand    nucleotide     count
    id1         12        +          A            13
    id1         13        +          C            25
    id2         24        +          G            10
    id2         25        +          T            25
    id2         26        +          A            10
    id3         10        +          C            5
```

But it has more than 100,000 rows in total, `seqnames` has 3138 levels. I would like to split it into lists of dataframes according to seqnames, so I used split function:

```
data_list <- split(data,data$seqnames)
```

But it only returns something like this:

```
List of 3138
 $ id1:'data.frame':    0 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ seqnames  : Factor w/ 3138 levels "id1","id2",..: 
  ..$ pos       : int(0) 
  ..$ strand    : Factor w/ 3 levels "+","-","*": 
  ..$ nucleotide: Factor w/ 8 levels "A","C","G","T",..: 
  ..$ count     : int(0) 
  ..$ sample_id : chr(0) 
 $ id2:'data.frame':    0 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ seqnames  : Factor w/ 3138 levels "id1","id2",..: 
  ..$ pos       : int(0) 
  ..$ strand    : Factor w/ 3 levels "+","-","*": 
  ..$ nucleotide: Factor w/ 8 levels "A","C","G","T",..: 
  ..$ count     : int(0) 
  ..$ sample_id : chr(0)
```

I can't figure out why it is like this because I have used it on a made up dataframe with all numbers (of course, not as many rows as this one) and it works.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you try with `drop = TRUE` i.e. `data_list <- split(data,data$seqnames, drop = TRUE)`

Comment: I tried it, and it returns a list of 60, instead of list of 3138. However, with this command, it did give me observations.

Comment: What is the issue with that list of 60?  If there are 60, I assume that you have 60 unique values in 'seqnames' i.e check for `nlevels(droplevels(data$seqnames))`

Comment: I am assuming that you have have a lot of unused levels in 'seqnames' as it is a factor.  Try with `data <- droplevels(data); data_list <- split(data, data$seqnames, drop = TRUE)`

Comment: I think you are right, I checked with one of the ids that I couldn't find in the list of 60 in the dataframe, and I couldn't find any information of it. However, do you know if I can still have the list of 3138, but for the ones that do not have values, just leave it null or blank?

Comment: That is what your original `split` does i.e. gives the data.frame with 0 rows.  You can change it to NULL though, i.e. `data_list <- split(data,data$seqnames)` i.e. without dropping the levels.  Then, change those with 0 rows to NULL i..e `data_list[sapply(data_list, nrow) == 0] <- NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just that there are many unused levels as the column 'seqnames' is a `factor`.  With `split`, there is an option to `drop` (`drop = TRUE` - by default it is `FALSE`) to remove those list elements.  Otherwise, they will return as `data.frame` with 0 rows.  If we want those elements to be replaced by `NULL`, then find those elements where the number of rows (`nrow`) are 0 and assign it to `NULL`

```
data_list <- split(data,data$seqnames)
> str(data_list)
List of 5
 $ id1:'data.frame':    2 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ seqnames  : Factor w/ 5 levels "id1","id2","id3",..: 1 1
  ..$ pos       : int [1:2] 12 13
  ..$ strand    : chr [1:2] "+" "+"
  ..$ nucleotide: chr [1:2] "A" "C"
  ..$ count     : int [1:2] 13 25
 $ id2:'data.frame':    3 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ seqnames  : Factor w/ 5 levels "id1","id2","id3",..: 2 2 2
  ..$ pos       : int [1:3] 24 25 26
  ..$ strand    : chr [1:3] "+" "+" "+"
  ..$ nucleotide: chr [1:3] "G" "T" "A"
  ..$ count     : int [1:3] 10 25 10
 $ id3:'data.frame':    1 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ seqnames  : Factor w/ 5 levels "id1","id2","id3",..: 3
  ..$ pos       : int 10
  ..$ strand    : chr "+"
  ..$ nucleotide: chr "C"
  ..$ count     : int 5
 $ id4:'data.frame':    0 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ seqnames  : Factor w/ 5 levels "id1","id2","id3",..: 
  ..$ pos       : int(0) 
  ..$ strand    : chr(0) 
  ..$ nucleotide: chr(0) 
  ..$ count     : int(0) 
 $ id5:'data.frame':    0 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ seqnames  : Factor w/ 5 levels "id1","id2","id3",..: 
  ..$ pos       : int(0) 
  ..$ strand    : chr(0) 
  ..$ nucleotide: chr(0) 
  ..$ count     : int(0)
```

Doing the assignment to `NULL`

```
data_list[sapply(data_list, nrow) == 0] <- list(NULL)
```

-check again

```
> str(data_list)
List of 5
 $ id1:'data.frame':    2 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ seqnames  : Factor w/ 5 levels "id1","id2","id3",..: 1 1
  ..$ pos       : int [1:2] 12 13
  ..$ strand    : chr [1:2] "+" "+"
  ..$ nucleotide: chr [1:2] "A" "C"
  ..$ count     : int [1:2] 13 25
 $ id2:'data.frame':    3 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ seqnames  : Factor w/ 5 levels "id1","id2","id3",..: 2 2 2
  ..$ pos       : int [1:3] 24 25 26
  ..$ strand    : chr [1:3] "+" "+" "+"
  ..$ nucleotide: chr [1:3] "G" "T" "A"
  ..$ count     : int [1:3] 10 25 10
 $ id3:'data.frame':    1 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ seqnames  : Factor w/ 5 levels "id1","id2","id3",..: 3
  ..$ pos       : int 10
  ..$ strand    : chr "+"
  ..$ nucleotide: chr "C"
  ..$ count     : int 5
 $ id4: NULL
 $ id5: NULL
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(seqnames = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("id1", 
"id2", "id3", "id4", "id5"), class = "factor"), pos = c(12L, 
13L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 10L), strand = c("+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+"), nucleotide = c("A", "C", "G", "T", "A", "C"), count = c(13L, 
25L, 10L, 25L, 10L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```